# localhost is currently unable to handle this request. HTTP ERROR 500

Tags: apache, web, mariadb

please help, I was having problems on my local web server,how do I fix the problem? 
I am using apache2, php7, MariaDB

[image]

when I open the html file with the extension could walk, but when the php file could not.

Comment: Please provide more details such as the contents of the php file. Error 500 is too vague.  Also, what do you mean by "when I open the html file with the extension could walk"?

Comment: The web servers error log should also have more information on what went wrong ...

Answer (score 0):

An error 500 would imply there is something wrong on the server-side, have you looked at the server logs?

use this command to find where php is located

```
whereis php
```

then open up terminal and type:

```
tail -n 20 /useThePathwhereisPhpGave/logs/php_error.log
```

This may give you some clue as to what is going on.

Hope this helps,